# unable to create a new partition. gparted error:" unable to satisfy ..."

Tags: partitioning, gparted

the title is similar to some post but it's not duplicated.
i have 5gigbaytes unallocated space between sda5 and ada6. i want to create a new partition with it but it says "Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition".
i use live cd of ubuntu 16.04.
here is output of 'fdisk -l'

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd9fa2484

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048    1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048  695230463 694204416   331G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        695230464 1114660863 419430400   200G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       1114662910 1953523711 838860802   400G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       1114662912 1338780099 224117188 106.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       1349267456 1534093311 184825856  88.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1534095360 1930083641 395988282 188.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8  *    1930084352 1937989631   7905280   3.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       1937991680 1953523711  15532032   7.4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: What program is producing that error message? `fdisk`? IIRC, that's usually a libparted error, which implies `parted` or GParted; but maybe I'm not remembering correctly, or maybe `fdisk` has picked up the same error language. In any event, the usual cause is that rounding of sector values has resulted in overlapping partitions. The solution is to deliberately alter the start and/or end points to leave a small gap between partitions. Alternatively, you could try another partitioning program.

Comment: gparted produce the error.

Comment: i was playing with setting in gparted and it solve the problem. i just change align to "cylander" and it create the partition.

Comment: Cylinder alignment on your disk is likely to degrade performance. See [this article I wrote on the subject](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-on-4kb-sector-disks/) for details. The fact that `fdisk` is reporting different physical and logical sector sizes for the disk means that it *is* affected by this issue.

Comment: I read the article. I don't understand it well but i understand why cylinder alignment degrade performance. what can i do to correct it?

Comment: One other thing. After I align sda6 with cylinder, fdisk says same thing for sda6.

Comment: Your `/dev/sda6` looks OK to me. There's a complaint about `/dev/sda4`, but it's an extended partition, to which this alignment rule doesn't apply because it holds just a 1-sector partition table data structure, not a filesystem. As to fixing the problem, you should either resize the start of the affected partition with 1 MiB alignment set or delete it and re-create it. As noted in my earlier comment, you may need to leave a small gap (~1 MiB) at the start and/or end of the partition to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description I assume that the gparted version in question is [v0.25.0-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gparted).  If that is true then you might have encountered [Bug 779339 - enforce at least 1 MiB "free space following"](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779339).

The work-around with MiB alignment is to leave at least 1 MiB unallocated space before and after logical partitions.

Comment: yes. that's v0.25.0.

Comment: i use fdisk to delete  my extended partition and create it again to solve the warning" Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary". it's really better than gparted in creating partitions